# String[0] vs ToCharArray then Char[0]

Tags: c#, .net, char

Say I want to get the third letter in a string.

```
string s = "cats";
```

what is the difference between using s[2] to get the value,
as I see most examples online use:

```
char[] c = s.ToCharArray();
char x = c[2];
```

Comment: s[2] is cleaner.  In my opinion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If you need a char at particular index, use `"cats"[2]`
- If you need the whole string as char array, use `"cats".ToCharArray()`

Comment: right.  Doing a ToCharArray in your situation would be overkill

Comment: Also, `string.GetEnumerator()` (when you `foreach` through a `string`, `char` at a time) does not create a copy of the string either. Meaning that it still would be more efficient than `.ToCharArray()` in many cases.

Comment: is there any benefit of one versus the other in, say a ReverseString method ?

Answer (score 4):

The `s[2]` method simply looks up the character in that position and returns it.

The `s.ToCharArray();` method allocates a new `char[]`, then `c[2]` looks it up in the array.

If you need just a single character, use the `s[2]` method as the `ToCharArray()` method is wasteful. If you need all the characters in the string as a `char[]` then the `ToCharArray()` method is cleaner and *probably* faster (I haven't done any benchmarking, so don't hold me to that).

**EDIT**:

Both MS.NET and Mono's implementations of `string.ToCharArray()` use unsafe code that pins the internal `char` and a duplicate `char[]` and operates on the pointers. This is definitely faster than calling the indexer for every character and is probably faster than using an enumerator to iterate over all the characters. Plus I find it a lot cleaner, especially in the case where it's used as a parameter:

```
DoSomethingWithCharArray(s.ToCharArray());
```

vs

```
int i = 0;
char[] arr = new char[s.Length];
foreach (char c in s)
{
    arr[i] = c;
    i++;
}

DoSomethingWithCharArray(arr);
```

or

```
char[] arr = new char[s.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = s[i];
}

DoSeomthingWithCharArray(arr);
```

Comment: *Why* is `ToCharArray()` better? It's possible, but I think it should be explained in this answer.

Comment: Well, it's cleaner than a for loop with `s[i]`, and it *probably* performs better, but I haven't done any benchmarking or tests so I decided not to assume that it does.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the expansion of the answer. I personally would consider running the `for` directly over `s` cleaner, but that's not really important. When I face the decision next time, I'll try and find out about some benchmarks :)

Comment: Looking at the .NET reference source, they pin both the internal `char[]` and a duplicate `char[]` and invoke the managed method `wstrcpy` which does some pointer math. This will be significantly faster than a for loop. [Mono's string implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs) pins both arrays and uses their own managed implementation of `memcpy`. I'd write my own benchmark but it's pretty clear that both implementations are faster than calling the indexer for every char (which has to pin and unpin the string for every char)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is exactly that you're creating a character array unnecessarily. Use s[2].

Answer (score 0):

If you're just reading the character the difference is only a slightly larger memory footprint. However, if you also want to change some characters and retain the original string then utilizing `ToCharArray` is very usefull.